# AMD 700, 800 series chipset. I'm lost

Tags: compatibility, chipset, multi-processor, amd-phenom

I've been an Intel / NVidia user ever since I started using computers.
Intel really gone up with the prices, and they won't get cheaper.

**So I decided to get an AMD.**

But WHICH one?
I mean.. not shopping question but.. what are the differences?
Like: 880GMA comes only with a single PCI ex and it looks like a chinese replica (no offense).
While 890FX comes with 5PCI-ex for QuadCrossfire.

Also.. what's the deal with 7xx series? I mean.. its the same price. Yet its older? Or why is it 7xx?

Isn't there a single chipset between? Not chinese YET it's durable/fine for long-term usage?
What it should know (desktop stuff):

- NVidia GPU (Zalman AMP2 GTX 260^2
  (one card))
- Phenom 1090T cpu
- A somewhat good audio.

**Any ideas which is the chipset I'm searching for?**
If this sounds too much of a shopping question, feel free to edit. I just want some clarification on these chipsets.

Comment: I just built a system with a 1090T.  I love it.

Comment: Nothing but Intel for me, worth every freaking penny.

Comment: BBlake .. well thats quite informative. :) Which chipset did YOU choose? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. In the end the picture became clear.
Check whether you need more than one PCI EX (890fx), or an integrated card (880).
If yo are fine with your own VGA, no crossfire and stuff, then 870 series.

(Forget about the 7xx series. Also, don't try to find a premium/platinum MB, there IS NO SUCH THING. It's a budget setup .. that's all. !)

(But the end I ended up buying an Intel i7 950 + Gigabyte X58A-UD3R :} I'm very happy with it.. best decision in this situation. Just as @moab and @harrymc said, worth EVERY single penny. !!!)

Answer (score 1):

There is some info in these articles:

[Intel vs AMD Processor Comparison 2010](http://www.buzzle.com/articles/intel-vs-amd-processor-comparison2010.html)
[AMD Versus INTEL Chips Comparison](http://www.buzzle.com/articles/amd-versus-intel-chips-comparison.html)
[PassMark Intel vs AMD CPU Benchmarks - High End](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/high_end_cpus.html)
[Comparison of AMD chipsets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_AMD_chipsets)

The latest link can show that Intel prices may be justified.
Here is a somewhat too general comparison from the first link:

[image]

Comment: ..it's not like an Intel VS AMD question. It's just ..that I'm lost about AMD chipsets. Any help with that? :-/

Comment: I added a 4th link above for AMD.

Comment: Yeah but... well..what would YOU choose? I saw clear attributes and stuff but that didn't bring me closer to the answer. It's like... they know the same, cost the same.. then what is the difference/catch?

Comment: Can't ask me as regarding AMD, as for performance I always choose Intel. You can take an Intel model that you like, and use the PassMark results to define your lowest AMD model. But CPU is not the only criteria - there is also RAM, bus, GPU and disk whose speed is also very important. GPU/CPU/RAM/bus is most important for gaming. You need to decide on a budget, then get the model you feel is the best compromise on *all* components. A recent model is always recommended.

Comment: On another note, I find that Dell computers are very good value and performance.

Answer (score 0):

Only difference I could read is 770 more SATA 3gig (2 / II), ACHI ver1.1 and the 870 counterpart is SATA 6gig (3 / III), ACHI ver1.2 .

[AMD Chipsets for Desktop PCs](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/chipsets/Pages/desktop-chipsets.aspx) (helps a little)

Shiki, any reason exact why "I/anyone" should forget about the 700 series? When you say budget and say you've purchased a (@current$$$) a $250+ mobo, along with a $275+ cpu (that aren't AMD ;P)...umm, in my opinion that's not budget. X

[AMD 8 Series Chipset Features Comparison](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/chipsets/8-series-integrated/Pages/amd-8-series-chipset-feature-comparison.aspx)

Can anyone link a Q&A here, regarding AMD/ATI on-board video "integrated" and nVidia graphics card. Would it be better to get a discrete mobo?